# Trying to add an image to Firebase storage then add the image location to a Firestore document

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to add an image to Firebase storage and then get the location of that image and store it in a Firestore document with the other user profile data. I am trying to do all of this when the user first creates an account. I was trying to use the image URL to do this but that does not appear to be working. When I run the code below it will sign up a new user and add the photo to Firebase storage but no document gets created in the Firestore database. What am I doing wrong?

```
@objc func handleSignUp() {

    //Signup properties
    guard let email = emailTextField.text else { return }
    guard let password = passwordTextField.text else { return }
    guard let fullName = fullNameTextField.text else { return }
    guard let username = usernameTextField.text?.lowercased() else { return }

    createUser(email: email,
               password: password,
               fullName: fullName,
               userName: username)
}

func createUser(email: String, password: String, fullName: String, userName: String) {
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (authResult, error) in

        //Handle error
        if let error = error {
            print("DEBUG: Failed to create user with error: ", error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        guard let profileImg = self.plusPhotoBtn.imageView?.image else { return }
        guard let uploadData = profileImg.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.3) else { return }

        let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
        let filename = NSUUID().uuidString

        //Storage location for photo in Firebase
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("profile_images").child(userID).child(filename)

        storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in

            //Handle error
            if let error = error {
                print("Failed to upload image to Firebase Storage with error", error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            guard metadata != nil else { return }

            let path = storageRef.fullPath;

            guard let username = self.usernameTextField.text?.lowercased() else { return }

            storageRef.downloadURL { (url, _) in

                let data = ["name": fullName,
                            "username": username,
                            "profileImagePath": path,
                            "email" : email] as [String : Any]

                self.addDocument(userData: data)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the issue you're getting?

Comment: While this `let filename = NSUUID().uuidString` is going to work (see @Amit answer for the fix),  it would make more sense to have a path of *storage/profile_pics/users_uid.jpg* instead of a randomly generated uuid, or if more data needs to be in storage for each user, give each their own storage 'space'  */storage/users uid/profile_pic.jpg* so you could then group each users stuff in one storage area */storage/users uid/my_dog.jpg* and */storage/users uid/sunset_photo.jpg*.

Comment: Jay that’s actually a really good point! I will create a file location based on the user id. I have done it that way in the past. I guess I got sidetracked with trying to get this part to work. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should add the "downloadURL" part inside the "putData".

After completion of the put data process you should try to get the URL or else it will fail.

Try this and see if it works:

```
@objc func handleSignUp() {

    //Signup properties
    guard let email = email.text else { return }
    guard let password = password.text else { return }
    guard let fullName = name.text else { return }
    guard let username = name.text?.lowercased() else { return }

    createUser(email: email,
               password: password,
               fullName: fullName,
               userName: username)
}

func createUser(email: String, password: String, fullName: String, userName: String) {
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (authResult, error) in

        //Handle error
        if let error = error {
            print("DEBUG: Failed to create user with error: ", error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        guard let profileImg = self.plusPhotoBtn.imageView?.image else { return }
        guard let uploadData = profileImg.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.3) else { return }

        let filename = NSUUID().uuidString

        //Storage location for photo in Firebase
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("profile_images").child(filename)

        storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in

            //Handle error
            if let error = error {
                print("Failed to upload image to Firebase Storage with error", error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            guard let metadata = metadata else { return }

            guard let username = self.usernameTextField.text?.lowercased() else { return }
            storageRef.downloadURL { (url, _) in

                guard let downloadURL = url else {
                    print("DEBUG: Profile image url is nil")
                    return
                }

                let data = ["name": fullName,
                            "username": username,
                            "profileImageUrl": downloadURL,
                            "email" : email]

                self.addDocument(userData: data)
            }
        })
    }
}

func addDocument(userData: [String: Any]) {
    Firestore.firestore().collection("profile_data").addDocument(data: userData) { (err) in
            if let err = err {
                debugPrint("Error adding document: \(err)")
            } else {
                self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer - well done! I am not enthused about this `let filename = NSUUID().uuidString` although nothing wrong with it as it was part of the OP's code.  I'll address that as a comment.

Comment: I updated my code based on some of the suggestions you and Jay made. I did however change some stuff. After reading some of the Firebase documentation I decided to use the storageRef.fullPath line that I added and figured I would later call it  FireBaseUI (https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files#downloading_images_with_firebaseui). What are your thoughts on this approach?

Comment: @Part_Time_Nerd I think it may work but would really need to see it posed as a question including the code you're asking about. Don't forget to accept this answer if it helped so it can help others.